# Change colour in html using php

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
    $id_pemesanan=$_GET['id_pemesanan'];

    $q="SELECT * FROM `seat`";
    $qe=mysql_query($q);
    $de=mysql_fetch_array($qe);

    $id_seat=$de['id_seat'];
    $row=$de['row'];
    $number=$de['number'];

    for ($i=1; $i <=$number ; $i++) { 
        echo "<li>
              <a href=\"book_seat_proses.php?id_pemesanan=".$id_pemesanan."&id_seat=".$id_seat."&number=".$i."\" id=".$row.$i."
              class=\"\"></a>
              </li>";
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to create a `seat_booking` system with three different color:

- white for available seat,
- black for reserved seat,
- green for your seat.

My plan is to add new class in `a` tag dynamically but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Don't know how to do what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use like

```
for ($i=1; $i <=$number ; $i++) {
        $color="";
        if($status=="available"){$color="Green";}
        else if($status=="Booked"){$color="Red";}
        else{$color="black";}

        echo '<a style="color:"'.$color.'"" href="...">Book Now</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

php:

```
for ($i=1; $i <=$number ; $i++) { 
    if( $status == 'available' )
    {
        echo '<a class="seat_available" href="...">Book Now</a>
    }
}
```

css:

```
.seat_available{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your classname in a variable and add it like you did with the href:

```
<?php
        $id_pemesanan=$_GET['id_pemesanan'];

        $q="SELECT * FROM `seat`";
        $qe=mysql_query($q);
        $de=mysql_fetch_array($qe);

        $id_seat=$de['id_seat'];
        $row=$de['row'];
        $number=$de['number'];
        $className= ...
        // do stuff to know your classname ('reserved'/'yours'/'available'). Don't forget to include your css with thoses classes.
        for ($i=1; $i <=$number ; $i++) { 
            echo "
                    <li>
                    <a href=\"book_seat_proses.php?id_pemesanan=".$id_pemesanan."&id_seat=".$id_seat."&number=".$i."\" id=".$row.$i."
                    class=\"".$className."\"></a>
                    </li>
            ";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable class like:

```
....
.....
$colorClass = 'green';
if ($status == 'available') {
    $colorClass = 'white';
} else if ($status == 'reserved') {
    $colorClass = 'black';
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    echo "
            <li>
            <a  class= '$colorClass' href=\"book_seat_proses.php?id_pemesanan=" . $id_pemesanan . "&id_seat=" . $id_seat . "&number=" . $i . "\" id=" . $row . $i . "
            class=\"\"></a>
            </li>
    ";
}
```

Add a css class for all the colors like:

```
 .black{
      color:black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code which set variable dynamic. here this $status is use for check if your field is different then use this instead $status.

```
$status=$de['status'];
```

to

```
$status=$de['yourfield'];
```

and one thing do you want to check this using loop in this case you need to use loop using your data array

```
for ($i=1; $i <=$number ; $i++) { 
    if( $status == 'available' )
    {
        $class ='white';
    } else if( $status == 'reserved' )
    {
        $class ='black';
    } else 
    {
        $class ='green';
    }

echo "
            <li>
            <a  class= '$class' href=\"book_seat_proses.php?id_pemesanan=" . $id_pemesanan . "&id_seat=" . $id_seat . "&number=" . $i . "\" id=" . $row . $i . "
            class=\"\"></a>
            </li>
    ";
}
```

then this is your css

```
.black{
      color:black;
      /* your extra code if need */
  }

.green{
      color:green;
     /* your extra code if need */
  }

.white{
      color:white;
      /* your extra code if need */
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have seat and seat_reserved table in my database.. which one should i add the status?

Comment: you are welcome and if my answer work then i will be happy

Comment: i think seat_reserved is your status . you save value like available, reserved in seat_reserved or seat filed ?

Comment: i'm confused where i add new coloumn in my database table for the status.. in seat or seat reserved ?

Comment: you can do using any table as your wish and your form structure . which your main table ? you use query from seat table so you add column in seat table

Comment: one thing i think you want to show this green , black or white from seat table and this will many row in table then need to update your main loop